# Cookies are working in localhost but not in production

Tags: node.js, cookies, cross-domain

I am using react and node js. In nodejs I send cookie thourgh cors. It is totally fine in development. That mean both react and node are in localhost. I receive cookie from react.
when I deploy react to netlify, i don't receive cookie anymore (node is still in localhost).
I think it is not cors problem because i can still access to other things

```
app.use(cors({
origin: 'https://ecstatic-shannon-a729e4.netlify.app',
credentials: true,
allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'x-auth-token'],
methods: "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE"
}));
```

something wrong with my code or it is not allowd to send cookies from localhost to webservice?

Comment: Did you move your backend to production? Is it still in your `localhost` or somewhere running in the cloud?

Comment: It is still in localhost

Comment: You need to deploy your server as well. Your React app now doesn't know what `localhost` is now.

Comment: So if i deploy my backend in heroku, it will be file, right?

Comment: yeah. Make sure you rename the endpoint in your react app to point to the backend, then it should work.

Comment: Thanks man i will try it. I've been searching a lot for that